# How can i notify subscriber of the API when that API is called?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket, stomp, messagebroker, rest

I have a Rest API like this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    private final EmpleyeeService employeeService;

    public EmployeeController(EmpleyeeService textService) {
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST , value = "/add-emplyee")
    public void addEmployee(){
        //TODO: receive emplyee from input
        employeeService.save(emplyee);
    }
    
}
```

I want when `addEmployee` Rest AOI is called then the clients who subscribe to this API get notified. So I created `WebsocketConfig` like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry){
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Is that correct? What else should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like that with this method(line 27)
[image: code]

check the full source here https://github.com/fajaralmu/base_web_app/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fajar/entitymanagement/service/RealtimeService2.java